# Creating, executing, and using a function in a single line in PHP

Tags: php

In JavaScript, I can create, execute, and use the `return` of an anonymous function in a single line, like this:

```
console.log(
    ( function() {
        return "Hi"
    } )()
);
```

I realise that you can accomplish the same in PHP using `call_user_func()`, like so:

```
echo(
    call_user_func(
        function() {
            return "Hi";
        }
    )
);
```

I'm wondering if there's any shorter way of doing this? Or is using `call_user_func()` really the best?

Comment: You can quite literally use the same syntax. This is perfectly valid PHP ~ `echo (function() { return 'hi'; })();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 7.0.0, you can use **[immediately-invoked function expressions (IIFEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)**:

```
<?php
echo (function() {
    return 42;
})();
```

This can be seen working on 3v4l **[here](https://3v4l.org/p0HS3)**.